# Jenkinsfile Environment variable does not reflect in the Makefile called within the script section

Tags: linux, jenkins, makefile, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below jenkins file, I am trying to print the environment variable, defined in the jenkins file, in the make file. But, it does not reflect in the make file. it remains empty.

```
pipeline {
  environment {
      CREDS = credentials('some jenkins credential id')
  }
  agent{
     kubernetes {
        label 'mypod'
        containerTemplate {
            name 'ubuntu'
            image 'ubuntu:16.04'
            ttyEnabled true
            command 'cat'
        }
    }
  }
  stages{
      stage('execute Makefile'){
         script{
           sh"""
             make print-jenkinsfile-env-var

             echo ${CREDS_USR}
             echo ${CREDS}

            """
         }

      }
  }
}
```

Below is my Makefile:

```
usercred := $(CREDS)
export usercred
username := $(CRED_USR)
export username
testuser := 'newvar'
export testuser
print-jenkinsfile-env-var:
     @echo "$$usercred"
     @echo "$$username"
     @echo "$$testuser"
```

Suggested edit in the make file, it did not print either.

```
usercred := $(CREDS)
export usercred
username := $(CRED_USR)
export username
testuser := 'newvar'
export testuser
print-jenkinsfile-env-var:
     @echo $(usercred)
     @echo $(username)
     @echo "$$testuser"
```

Testuser gets printed, as it was defined in the Makefile, but the other two variables printed empty.
I am able to print the env vaiables in the script section explicitly, but not though the makefile.

I am looking for the below to work

```
push-package:
#tgz file creation step
#push the package 
@curl -u $(CREDS) -X PUT "jfrog artifactory repo url" -T *tgz
```

But, my Makefile does not get the value for $(CRED) that is there in the Jenkins file environment. However, I can execute the same script like below in the Jenkinsfile

```
curl -u ${CREDS} -X PUT "jfrog artifactory repo url" -T *tgz
```

Can someone suggest?

Comment: You are setting `usercred` as a make variable, but referencing it in your target as a shell variable. Use `@ echo $(usercred)` instead

Comment: I did, but it did not print. Basically, I am looking for directly using the user cred for the below script:
@curl -u $(CREDS) -X PUT "jfrog artifactory repo url" -T *tgz

But the creds does not reflect in the make file, thus not able to push the package.

Comment: You could call `make ... CREDS=${CREDS}` and in your makefile `@echo $(usercred)`. Your `username` is empty because `CRED_USR` is never set, so emtpy too

Comment: thank you very much Zelnes. you saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the help from Zelnes, who commented in on my post, I did the below changes, and i was able to use the jenkinsfile env var into my makefile. I made the below change in the jenkins file.

```
script{
       sh"""
         make print-jenkinsfile-env-var CREDS=${CREDS}

        """
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try directly using below in Makefile

```
usercred := ${CREDS}
export usercred
username := ${CRED_USR}
```